# Windows OpenVPN server , clients cant reach LAN behind server

Tags: openvpn

I`m trying to setup an Windows OpenVPN server to share the network behind this server.

On Linux I`ve done this several times. However on a Windows server I don`t have any luck getting this to work.

I setup the routes and enabled IP forwarding using this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
Value Name: IPEnableRouter
Set the following registry value:
Value Name: IPEnableRouter
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```

Rebooted the server afterwards.

From the clients, I can reach the server on both LAN IP and OpenVPN IP. However, I cant access any devices in the LAN subnet.

When I run tracert to an IP (not the servers one) in the LAN subnet, I can see its routed through the OpenVPN server.

```
Tracing route to 192.168.30.9 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     8 ms     7 ms     7 ms  SBS [10.9.0.1]
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

OpenVPN server config:

```
 port 1195

 proto udp


 dev tun


 dev-node OVPN


 ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
 cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.crt"
 key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.key"  

 dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh1024.pem"


 topology subnet


 server 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0


 ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
```

What am I missing here?

```
 push "route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0"
 push "route 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0"
 ;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"


 duplicate-cn


 keepalive 10 120


 comp-lzo


 persist-key
 persist-tun


 status openvpn-status.log


 verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows can only act as a router if the "Routing and Remote Access" service is running. Can you confirm that this service is started? If it is started, then check if the Windows Firewall is enabled. If it is, disable it and try your `tracert` again.

Hope this helps